# Android - Do not generate values-v26

Tags: android, sdk, kotlin

I build an app in **Kotlin with SDK 25**.

Now, after Android Studio update, I get this error:

```
.../audiobook/build/intermediates/res/merged/opensource/debug/values-v26/values-v26.xml
  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
Execution failed for task ':audiobook:processOpensourceDebugResources'.
  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I know that I should update my Gradle dependencies to SDK 26, but if I do it, then I need to rewrite all my Kotlin code as there are many changes between SDK 25 and SDK 26.

Is there any way how **not to generate values-v26 files when I am only on SDK 25 in my Gradle**? Thanks.

[Here is screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZYTs.png)

Comment: Why do you think you'd need to rewrite so much code?  There are differences between 25 and 26, but there's very little that would trigger a massive rewrite.  Its unusual on Android for updating SDK versions to require more than a few minor tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should align your support/design libraries to your SDK version (25 in your case). For instance,

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25+'
```

Next, you have two solutions:

1. Downdgrade the librairies which have transitive dependency with SDK 26
2. If you are lucky and the library you use is hosted at github, you can fork the project, rearrange the gradle file to meet SDK 25. Finally, make a realease of your forked library and import it. Your library will be hosted at [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/)